# disable enqueued Javascript on mobile in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile, tablet

I'm a beginner in wordpress, I'm trying to add [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)
to my wordpress theme, and everything is working fine on the desktop but not on the ipad or iphone..
here's my enqueued code:`function skrollr_scripts() {

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'skrollr_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/myscript.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
```

}` I was wondering if there's any way I can disable the javascript files ONLY on mobile devices?

Comment: check this post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166086/dont-load-scripts-if-on-mobile-tablet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace the code

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'skrollr_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/myscript.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
```

with

```
if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'skrollr_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/myscript.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
}
```

This will solve your problem.